# How to get the SupportFragmentManager of a Fragment context in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was using the StoryView for my Chat project. Link-
[StoryView Github](https://github.com/OMARIHAMZA/StoryView)

Since a recycler view is needed to show the stories, I also made a adapter. The fragment code of the storyview show-

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentStatusBinding binding;
FirebaseDatabase db;
public StatusFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentStatusBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

    return binding.getRoot();
}}
```

I want to show the stories in this fragment. The adapter code is-

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopStatusViewHolder holder, int position) {
    UserStatus us = US.get(position);
    Status lastStatus = us.getStatuses().get(us.getStatuses().size()-1); //showing the recent picture user uploaded

    Glide.with(cx).load(lastStatus.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(holder.binding.circleImageView);
    holder.binding.circularStatusView.setPortionsCount(us.getStatuses().size()); //getting the number of pictures user uploaded
    holder.binding.StatusName.setText(us.getName()); //showing the user's name

    holder.binding.circularStatusView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        ArrayList<MyStory> myStories = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Status status: us.getStatuses()){
            myStories.add(new MyStory(status.getImageUrl(), new Date(status.getTimestamp())));
        }

        new StoryView.Builder(((StatusFragment)cx).getChildFragmentManager()).setStoriesList(myStories)
                .setStoryDuration(4000).setTitleText(us.getName())
                .setSubtitleText("").setTitleLogoUrl(us.getProfileImage())
                .setStoryClickListeners(new StoryClickListeners() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDescriptionClickListener(int position) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTitleIconClickListener(int position) {

                    }
                }).build().show();
    });
}
```

I just showed the onBindViewHolder code portion because that's where the problem is. The problem is in this portion specifically-

> StoryView.Builder(((StatusFragment)cx).getChildFragmentManager())

As you can see here, the typecasting used the StatusFragment, because I want to show the storyview there. But there is an error and I don't know how to solve it. I have also used **getParentFragmentManager()** but same error. The error is-

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.joycse.chatty30.fragment.StatusFragment'

Normally it should be like this (accordingly a video I saw)-

> new StoryView.Builder(((MainActivity)cx).getSupportFragmentManager())

There should be an activity and getSupportFragmentManager works perfectly there, because I guess it's a full activity, not a fragment. But I wanted to use it on a fragment, not on an activity. What should I use here to solve that error?

The full adapter class code below-

```
package com.joycse.chatty30.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.joycse.chatty30.R;
import com.joycse.chatty30.databinding.ItemStatusBinding;
import com.joycse.chatty30.fragment.StatusFragment;
import com.joycse.chatty30.model.Status;
import com.joycse.chatty30.model.UserStatus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import omari.hamza.storyview.StoryView;
import omari.hamza.storyview.callback.StoryClickListeners;
import omari.hamza.storyview.model.MyStory;

public class TopStatusAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<TopStatusAdapter.TopStatusViewHolder> {
Context cx;
ArrayList<UserStatus> US; //*

public TopStatusAdapter(Context cx, ArrayList<UserStatus> US) {
    this.cx = cx;
    this.US = US;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TopStatusViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(cx).inflate(R.layout.item_status,parent,false);
    return new TopStatusViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopStatusViewHolder holder, int position) {
    UserStatus us = US.get(position);
    Status lastStatus = us.getStatuses().get(us.getStatuses().size()-1); //showing the recent picture user uploaded

    Glide.with(cx).load(lastStatus.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(holder.binding.circleImageView);
    holder.binding.circularStatusView.setPortionsCount(us.getStatuses().size()); //getting the number of pictures user uploaded
    holder.binding.StatusName.setText(us.getName()); //showing the user's name

    holder.binding.circularStatusView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        ArrayList<MyStory> myStories = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Status status: us.getStatuses()){
            myStories.add(new MyStory(status.getImageUrl(), new Date(status.getTimestamp())));
        }

        new StoryView.Builder(getContext().getSupportFragmentManager()).setStoriesList(myStories)
                .setStoryDuration(4000).setTitleText(us.getName())
                .setSubtitleText("").setTitleLogoUrl(us.getProfileImage())
                .setStoryClickListeners(new StoryClickListeners() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDescriptionClickListener(int position) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTitleIconClickListener(int position) {

                    }
                }).build().show();
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return US.size();}

public class TopStatusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ItemStatusBinding binding;
    public TopStatusViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = ItemStatusBinding.bind(itemView);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> ```
> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.joycse.chatty30.fragment.StatusFragment'
> ```

you are trying to cast android.content.Context to your fragment class called StatusFragment. your cx variable (which is a context) cannot cast to your custom fragment directly.

**Inside StatusFragment:**

```
$YourAdapter adapter = new $YourAdapter (this //pass your custom fragment here,);
```

**Adapter constructor**

```
StatusFragment fragment
public $YourAdapter(StatusFragment fragment, ) {
this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

**Then use it to your onBindHolder;**

```
new StoryView.Builder(fragment.getChildFragmentManager())
```

Comment: So no Context variable? Instead of cx, I need to have StatusFragment variable?

Comment: you still use cx. what i meant is you cannot directly cast it to your fragment directly

Comment: Okay, that means three parameters in the constructor right? Context, fragment and arraylist.

Comment: Before this answer, were you creating the instance of the adapter in your fragment class? Like this `TopStatusAdapter adapter=new TopStatusAdapter(getContext(), yourArrayList) `?

Comment: Nope, I thought I could do that later. But anyway, the problem is solved. Thank you so much you all. I do have another problem about this storyview which is a bit more logical problem rather than syntax, but I will ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `StoryView.Builder(((StatusFragment)cx).getChildFragmentManager())`

As this is the manager responsible for handling transactions in fragment.

Comment: I have done that as well. Both getChild and getParent gives the same error message which is Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.joycse.chatty30.fragment.StatusFragment'

Comment: This approach is suitable when the StatusFragment is hosted within another fragment, not directly within an activity.

Comment: Yeah right. I think it says child because the fragment is in another fragment. But I don't know how to get the fragment manager when the fragment is inside an activity.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you are trying to cast Context to StatusFragment, and you cannot directly cast a Context to a Fragment. To show the StoryView in a fragment, you should obtain the FragmentManager associated with the hosting activity of the fragment.

Try this instead to solve the error.

```
// Use the getActivity() method to get the hosting activity, and then get its FragmentManager.
    new StoryView.Builder(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()).setStoriesList(myStories)
```

Comment: It shows this error- Cannot resolve method 'getActivity' in 'TopStatusAdapter' TopStatusAdapter is the name of the Adapter by the way.

Comment: try getContext()

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getContext' in 'TopStatusAdapter' No luck it seems.

Comment: please share the complete code of the TopStatusAdapter class, I think the problem is with it.

Comment: Would you please check the question again? I edited the Adapter class code very last. You can find the full code there. And let me know if you want to check any other code as well. Thanks.

Comment: try `Builder(((AppCompatActivity) cx)` or this `Builder(((Activity) cx)`

Comment: wow, AppCompatActivity worked as well!